# What is new in the Director's Cut of Wasteland 2?

Tags: wasteland-2, wasteland-2-directors-cut

I've been trying to find information about the differences between *Wasteland 2* and *Wasteland 2: Director's Cut*. I found [a great graphics comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=py64nlDSAJQ), but I'm more interested in the changes to gameplay, new features, and other improvements.

What things are new in the Director's Cut of *Wasteland 2*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the answer from their [website](https://wasteland.inxile-entertainment.com/backer-information/release-faq):

What is new in the Director's Cut?
Wasteland 2 Director's Cut changes a huge number of aspects of the game. Our main new features and changes include:

- Graphical overhaul and update to the Unity 5 game engine.
- Expanded voice-over with thousands of newly-voiced lines for key characters and scenes.
- Precision Strikes system allows you to target individual body parts on enemies in combat, which lets you inflict negative status effects on them.
- Perks system lets you pick bonuses for your characters as they level up.
- Quirks system lets you pick a personality trait for each custom created Ranger during character creation, with a gameplay-modifying positive and negative quality.
- Rebalanced gameplay, including virtually all combat encounters, weapons, loot drops and containers.
- Controller support on PC and console. On PC, you can select from keyboard and mouse input, as well as Xbox 360, Xbox One and PlayStation 4 DUALSHOCK 4 controller modes.
- There's plenty of smaller additions to be found, of course, but we'll leave those for you to find.

Comment: Do you know if the "smaller additions" are plot-related, or just minor improvements (e.g. UI changes)?

Comment: Sorry, that's all I found about the D.C.  That and the fact it is a rebrand of the game of the year. I don't know if there are any plot changes. I installed and reinstalled this game a million times. I need a good character creation guide.

Comment: I didn't see any plot changes when I played through it again, but I might have missed them because of the path I took...